# xinput keycodes do not align with xmodmap table

Tags: bash, text-processing, x11

Is there a table that maps keycodes from the command `xinput test-xi2 --root 3` to keysyms?

I've tried `xmodmap -pke` which I found in the ArchWiki but they don't correspond. How does X even interact with the keyboard?
Can you guys point me to some resources that explains how X handles key input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very brief outline:

Depending on the hardware, the key events go through various kernel layers, and end up in the "input" layer. For a USB keyboard, the layers are

```
"USB events" --> "HID events" --> "Input events".
```

Kernel layer input events are available on `/dev/input/eventX` (with the usual symlinks for a specific device). You can use `evtest` to have a look.

The X `evdev` driver picks up those events.

There are two different mapping mechanisms in X, the `xkbd` one (which is pretty complicated, see [an Unreliable Guide to XKB Configuration](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.600.7058)), and the one you can control with `xmodmap`.

If you use `xev`, you should see the mappings you can control with `xmodmap`.

XInput (both version 1 and 2) are also later additions, and I do not know on which level `xinput test-xi2` works. On my system, they seem to match the keycodes I see in `xev`, so concrete examples where yours don't match would help.